# Having trouble setting Many-to-one relationships in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, model, relationship

I'm trying to rewrite my django models in order to solve some problems I found.

I have 4 models: a Task, a Request, a Product and a Location.

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)

class Request(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(to = Product, related_name = "product", on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    task = models.ForeignKey(to = Task, related_name = "task", on_delete = models.CASCADE) 

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    service_time = models.FloatField()
    start_location = models.ForeignKey(to = Location, related_name = "start_location", on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    end_location = models.ForeignKey(to = Location, related_name = "end_location", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    task_type = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

I'm currently strugling with the relationships. My main goal is to be able to make a POST request. Just like this one

```
{
    "name": "task1",
    "priority": 1,
    "service_time": 1200,
    "start_location": {
      "name": "loc1",
      "lat": 1,
      "long": 1
    },
    "end_location": {
      "name": "loc2",
      "lat": 1,
      "long": 1
    },
    "task_type": "pickup & delivery",
    "requests": [
    {
      "product": {
        "name":"Apples"
      },
      "quantity": 1000
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "name":"Kiwis"
      },
      "quantity": 2000
    }
  ] 
}
```

Some important points:

- I want to able to create Locations (if they don't exist) using this POST request.
- The Products will be already created and in the system
- Each Task can have multiple Requests and Each request is unique

How can I be able to create the requests using the POST? I don't even have a requests field in the Task model, and I'm not sure how to do it.
I know this should be an easy problem to fix, but I need some help.
Also, I don’t put the serializers here since I don’t have the finished models yet.

EDIT: As requested, I will try to explain better what I want to achieve.
With this models, (assuming correct Serializers) will I be able to handle this type of POST requests? Or am I going to have problems with the "requests" field?
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I don't see a problem with your models. They look well designed to me. Maybe adding a unique multi-column constraint on `Request` for product and task, but that's minor. What do you see as wrong?

Comment: As for having `requests` field in your `Task` model, this is what the `related_name` is for. Specify it as `requests` and Django will automatically create a field with this name in your `Task` model.

Comment: I'm not posting my suggestion as an answer, because you're asking for more than that. Please edit your question to ask for the solution of only one problem at a time.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answers. I will try to edit the question.
@GwynBleidD You're saying that I should have a related_name "requests". Are you referring to the one named "task" on my Request model?

Comment: @k3nz0 Django creates a Related manager on the reverse side of your foreign keys or other related fields. By default this is the current model name in lowercase with `_set` appended, which can be changed by specifying `related_name`. So currently if you have an instance of `Task` as `task` you can write `task.task.all()` to access all the related `Request` instances (this reflects your incorrect naming style of `related_name` hence `task.task`, by default this would have been `task.request_set`).

Comment: I'm trying to follow your recomendations. Is there a way that i can either create an Object Location or instead, pass its FK?

Just like this
`"start_location": {
      "name": "loc1",
      "lat": 1,
      "long": 1
    }`

And I can also do `"start_location" : 1,`